# How to use exclude option in file-loader with webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

How to exclude files if file being included is from specific path, in webpack using with file-loader plugin. Currently my webpack config file is as below.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        exclude : '/files/',         <====== This is not working.
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I tried as above, but it not working, as it should. Do excluding files work with webpack, file-loader plugin?